# Как подключить animate.css в карусель owl или slick?

Tags: javascript, css

Добрый день!
Подскажите, как настроить карусель owl вместе с animate.css, чтобы эффект при инициализацие и прокрутке был как [на этой странице](https://undsgn.com/uncode/top-deejay-headphones/) в разделе RELATED POSTS.

С подключением самой библиотеки проблем нет - все работает. Затруднение вызывает именно реализация эффекта при инициализации и прокрутке.
Вычитала, что раньше в документации были такие свойства, как afterMove and beforeMove. Но сейчас они отсутствуют.
Можно ли как то еще реализовать такую штуку без особых костылей?

Интересует этот же вопрос для карусели slick.

Answer (score 2):

Знаю что вопрос возможно устарел, все же может кому то пригодится.
В owlcarousel2 сейчас используют animateOut и animateIn.

```
$('.custom1').owlCarousel({
    animateOut: 'slideOutDown',
    animateIn: 'flipInX'
});
```

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/animate.html